# Funds or Money?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, money

I'm having an ongoing dispute in my organization over whether to use the word "funds" or "money" to describe, um, money that we award to grant applicants.

My position is that a fund holds money. When we take a portion of that fund, and pay it to a grantee, we award them money, not funds.

At times I've taken out my wallet and described it as a fund and the dollar bills inside of it as money. I can't pay for something by handing the cashier my wallet; I have to take the money out of the fund.

I'd appreciate any insight or advice on this usage.

thanks

Comment: Does [a dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fund) not help with this? *Funds* is not necessarily just the plural of *fund*.

Comment: Another dictionary [(AHDEL)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fund) is also a fund of relevant information:  **fund** 2 :
a. A sum of money or other resources set aside for a specific purpose: _a pension fund_.
b. **funds**: Available money; ready cash: _short on funds_. I _would_ add that the use of 'funds' rather than 'money', 'cash', 'readies' when paying for a burger sounds pretentious or jocular.

Comment: Bouncing a check means it is returned for Insufficient Funds, not Insufficient Money.

Comment: Why not compromise on *monies*?

Comment: @TimLymington I've already lost that battle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your position is wrong. While a *fund* can indeed hold money, that's not the sole accepted and established definition of *funds*, particularly in the plural. [One dictionary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/funds) says, quite simply, "financial resources". [Another](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/funds) says: "money that is readily available".

Yes, I *can* use funds to pay the cashier for my milkshake.

I've heard the word *funds* used often to describe organizational resources tied to grants. The [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/funds) website shows several example usages along these same lines, such as:

> Edmonston, Maryland used more than **$1 million in funds** from the American Recovery and Reinvestment Act to transform its main street from a flood-prone hazard to a "green street" that diverts storm water to keep it from overflowing and polluting the Anacostia River.
>
> Current operations The Adolescent Girls Initiative public-private partnership, with its  **$20 million in funds**, is already at work in seven countries, with plans to expand to aiti and Yemen.
>
> The bank had filed for **$11 million in funds** from the program.

Comment: It's normal usage to apply for *funds* or *funding* rather than *money* so I can't agree with your position. Perhaps this usage is slightly euphemistic.

Comment: We're addressing two issues here: (1) Can the term 'funds' be applied to monies as well as the bodies / trusts ... holding money. (2) [Correctly] assuming the answer to (1) is 'yes', are the terms 'funds' and 'money' interchangeable when speaking of the money?

Comment: @TheMathemagician - Yes, we apply for funds, and the agency that gives money provides the funding. That's the normal way we say it. But to argue that the _funds_ are the "wallet" and the money allocated is therefore the, "um, money" is too rigid an interpretation in the other direction, at least in my mind.

Comment: @J.R. you have a point. A fund does not necessarily only hold cash. My wallet contains funds in the form of cash, credit, and debit. Perhaps that analogy is imperfect. Fine.

Comment: I think @EdwinAshworth gets to the heart of the matter: Can "Funds" and "Money" be used interchangeably? I don't believe that they ought to be, at least, that is what I would prefer for our internal style. The aversion to using "money" seems to be only that it seems uncouth and "funds" is a more refined way to say it.
We ask "how much money do you have in your account?" Not, "how many funds do you have in your account?" Isn't the account a fund? How many funds are in your fund is dumb unless this is a 'fund of funds' mutual fund.

Comment: @Vidro3: I never said the words could be used interchangeably. Some words are interchangeable in some contexts, but two words are rarely always interchangeable. Moreover, even Edwin in his comment added a qualifier: "when speaking of money." Yes, "How much funds are in your fund" sounds dumb. But "We need to figure out how to distribute this year's grant funds" is NOT dumb (in fact, it's quite acceptable). Getting back to the question you asked, _funds_ can indeed refer to the money that you award to grant applicants – depending on how the rest of the sentence is worded, of course.

Comment: @J.R. Didn't mean to insinuate you favored interchangeable use. I'd give you an upvote if I had the rep to do so. 
I still prefer to use "money" if "funds" is only being used as a euphemism for the more "crass" term. 
How about these sentences: 
"If the estimated construction cost exceeds the grant award, the applicant must bring their own funding to the meeting." or "...must add their own funds to the account." 
"Your grant award funds may only be used for X,Y,Z." 
From a questionnaire:
Amount of Funds Awarded___
Amount of Funds Spent ___
Amount of Funds Remaining ___

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if _money_ is a "more crass" term, but sometimes _money_ works better for cash transactions, and _funds_ works better when the money is distributed in some other manner, such as an [EFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_funds_transfer). P.S. "If the estimated construction cost exceeds the grant award, the applicant must fund the difference, or obtain other funding." There are a myriad of ways to say it.

Comment: @J.R. I don't find it to be more crass, I think it is simpler and more direct. I was trying to describe the reasoning of the 'pro-funds' camp. Anyway, I hope we can agree that eschewing all uses of "money" is as bad as my position eschewing most uses of "funds". Our SOP on grant awards uses "fund(s)" 208 times and "money" once. For the sake of variation you'd think the "money" could be in there a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst economics is a science, accountancy is an art. Terms differ in the nuances they comport. There are no hard and fast rules as to when one would use 'funds' and when 'money', any more than when one would cry and when one would weep.

But as someone who spent his working life in the UK's Accountancy profession, I can say that in the example you cite, either term would work. Having said that I would probably use neither. My inclination would be to call it what it is, namely a 'grant'.

If you are intent on acquiring a financial vocabulary, the Oxford Dictionary of Economics, of which unfortunately I do not have a copy to hand, is probably as good a place as any to start. But beware that there are important differences between US and UK financial vocabulary. Though the terms you cite here are, in my experience, universal enough that that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I come from an accounting field and what I can tell is, what you hold as of now, you know collected over the period of time is 'funds' while, 'money' is more like a transactional thing like, what you have at a point of time.

Answer (score -3):

Don't ever use "funds" other than as a synonym for "accounts."

Comment: A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.